# How can I use the viewport meta tag for the Galaxy S3?

Tags: html, responsive-design, viewport, galaxy

I am trying to set the viewport width on the Galaxy S3, but the result is wired.

```
<meta id="ctl00_meta" name="viewport" content="width=640" />
```

This viewport is working on iPhone and other devices, but not on the Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `, target-densitydpi=device-dpi` to your content.